# Select data of a table LIKE data of other table

Tags: php, mysql

I have **two tables**,eg. `atab` and `btab` using mysql query:
Please help me with this following illustration (I'm relative new in mysql):

`SELECT * FROM atab WHERE column1 LIKE` (`column2` in the table `btab`);

Since the select query (2nd table) doesn't appoint to single row but LIKE (in whole rows), it will (perhaps) take too long to show the data, right?
How to optimize it? is it possible?

Comment: is there any relation between two tables?

Comment: Not sure, since it is like to see if there is a value of the 2nd table similar to values in 1st table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `EXISTS`:

```
select *
from atab a
where exists (
        select 1
        from btab b
        where a.column1 like concat('%',b.column2,'%')
        );
```

Comment: It works, but it takes about 12 seconds to show the data. How to make it faster?

Comment: that's because the like can't make use of indexes. You should look for other options - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: useful link. It's a matter of value inside the row then. thanks ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Try to this query

```
SELECT * FROM atab WHERE column1 LIKE (select column2 from btab);
```